# Get value from a hashmap while key is an arabic char

Tags: java, eclipse, hashmap

I'm writing a program which has a `HashMap` as seen here:

```
private static Map<String,Integer> myMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
```

**I already know that the key goes first** but every time I want to add a Arabic character as key, the code change and looks like this

```
myMap .put("س",60);
myMap .put("ش",300);
myMap .put("ص",90);
myMap .put("ض",800);
myMap .put("ط",9);
```

as you see my keys are some Arabic characters and values are `Integer`. But the order automatically changed when I put Arabic chars in my code. **Seems like is an encoding issue**. I'm using **Eclipse**, how can I fix this?

Comment: Why not use a `Map<Character,Integer>`?

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: *"i wonder why here keys go to right side of put() method! but in eclipse they are in right side, i.e. they are keys"* ... they aren't on the right, the key is on the left and that's unrelated to the IDE.

Comment: You seem to confuse keys and values, in your example you're using `put("ط",9)` where `9` is the *key* and `ط` is the *value*

Comment: And yes, even if you would write `put("س,"60);` that would be wrong. Because you probably wanted the arabic char to be the key. Here "60" is the key, and the arabic char is the value of the map!

Comment: the problem seems to be that Arabic chars are formatted from right to left

Comment: @elbraulio Even if they're formatted from right to left, this does not change the java syntax, where the method is `put(key, value)`

Comment: @Mark i have tried to add that key on intellij IDE and the syntax exploded when I added arabic chars.

Comment: @elbraulio You're right, this is really weird. After copy and pasting the code in the question into eclipse it's formatted the other way around, no clue what's going on. It even compiles for me.

Comment: Above code works fine (and is displayed in a sane way, with parameters in the correct order) when pasted into Elipse - possibly an issue in the IDE with right-to-left literals?

Comment: This should not even compile

Comment: The above code does compile.  The first line is actually `myMap .put("\u0633",60);`.  The apparent ordering of characters is correct according to the Unicode BIDI algorithm.  The only way I can think of to make it readable is with override control characters like [LRO](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202d/index.htm).

Comment: @Hulk - Yep I agree. I think Eclipse is re-interpreting the order of the characters because it's detected Arabic chars. His first mistake was using Eclipse :p

Comment: Which version of Ecliplse are you using? I cannot reproduce the problem with `Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0)`. What are your settings in `Window-> Preferences->Globalization`? If they are on OS Default, are you using RTL-settings in the OS?